# How make this slider to auto play

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get this slider to auto play in Javascript but I can't seem to get it to work, Does anyone know how I can achieve this? Every time I tried something it seemed to break the slider.

**jsfiddle version**: http://jsfiddle.net/BijanZand/7zebthjp/

Here is the current code:

> ```
> $(function() {
> $("#t1").mouseover(function() {
>     $("#t2").removeClass("current");
>     $(this).addClass("current");
>     $("#newTrend").fadeOut(function() {
>         $("#newContent").fadeIn();
>     });
> });
> $("#t2").mouseover(function() {
>     $("#t1").removeClass("current");
>     $(this).addClass("current");
>     $("#newContent").fadeOut(function() {
>         $("#newTrend").fadeIn();   
>       });
>   });
>   });
> ```

Comment: Do you mean that you want to "auto-play" through the tabs?

Comment: I would suggest making a function for changing the current tab (changing out the .mouseover anonymous functions with that function while you're at it) and using [setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setInterval) to change the tab.

Comment: i do this, but dont work! can you test this in fiddle ?

Answer (score 3):

***Just a quick solution :***

Recursively switching between functions will let you have your requirement fulfilled. But of course you have other better options to reach your goal.

**jQuery :**

```
A();

function A(){
        $("#t2").removeClass("current");
        $("#t1").addClass("current");
        $("#newTrend").fadeOut(300, function() {
            $("#newContent").fadeIn();
            B();
        });
}

function B(){
        $("#t1").removeClass("current");
        $("#t2").addClass("current");
        $("#newContent").fadeOut(500, function() {
            $("#newTrend").fadeIn();
            A();
        });
}
```

[***jsFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/52b0rh8e/)

Comment: change the first parameter of .fadeOut() function.Increase the value to slower switching. In this case change it to higher value like 3000.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(function() {
    var both = $('#t1, #t2'),
        run = function() {return window.setInterval(function() {
            both.not('.current').trigger('mouseover', 1);
        }, 1000);},
        play = run();
    both.mouseout(function() {play = run();});

    both.eq(0).mouseover(function(ev, data) {
        if (!data) window.clearInterval(play);
        both.eq(1).removeClass("current");
        $(this).addClass("current");
        $("#newTrend").fadeOut(function() {
            $("#newContent").fadeIn();
        });
    });
    both.eq(1).mouseover(function(ev, data) {
        if (!data) window.clearInterval(play);
        both.eq(0).removeClass("current");
        $(this).addClass("current");
        $("#newContent").fadeOut(function() {
            $("#newTrend").fadeIn();   
        });
    });
});
```

A working [DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/7zebthjp/10/). The autoplay stops when you hover over a tab and starts again when the mouse goes out.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the below code with your existing code

```
var changeit = function(){
    $('#newTrendTap li:not(.current)').trigger('mouseover');
    setTimeout(changeit,3000);
}

changeit();
```

Check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7zebthjp/13/)

Answer (score 0):

Try my Example.

HTML Code

```
 <div id="tt" class="easyui-tabs" style="width:330px;height:270px;">
    <div title="Shirt1" style="padding:20px;">
      <img src="images/shirt1.gif">
      </div>
    <div title="Shirt2" style="padding:20px;">
      <img src="images/shirt2.gif">
     </div>
     <div title="Shirt3" style="padding:20px;">
     <img src="images/shirt3.gif">
    </div>
    <div title="Shirt4" style="padding:20px;">
     <img src="images/shirt4.gif">
    </div>
    <div title="Shirt5" style="padding:20px;">
      <img src="images/shirt5.gif">
    </div>
</div>
```

Auto Play Code.

```
     var index = 0;
     var t = $('#tt');
     var tabs = t.tabs('tabs');
     setInterval(function(){
      t.tabs('select', tabs[index].panel('options').title);
       index++;
       if (index >= tabs.length){
       index = 0;
       }
       }, 3000);
```

Comment: can you fiddle this ?

Comment: load big js file my friend!